# Unable to login with Remote Mysql Server in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

[image: I am facing the Error:access denied for this user xyz which is created in CPanel database wizard .Now I want to access that database which is created in cpanel with host 172.17.0.1 and port 3306 in Docker container using mysql-client,it showing access denied error.Please help me to solve this issue]

I am facing the Error:access denied for this user xyz which is created in CPanel database wizard .Now I want to access that database which is created in cpanel with host  172.17.0.1 and port 3306  in Docker container using mysql-client,it showing access denied error.Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

> A local user is not the same thing as a remote user. For example
>   fooUser@localhost is not the same as fooUser@1.2.3.4. If you want both
>   users to have the same permissions, you need to duplicate permissions.

Make sure that your user is granted access from localhost and 127.0.0.1

[Source: Connect to your mysql database remotely](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/)